# How to get the nsmutablearray data into float

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsmutablearray

getting dataset as like below

```
Webservices *details=[[Webservices alloc] init];
[details getMobileNumberDetails:phnotextfield.text];    
NSLog(@"longitudes Arrays from %@",details.resultData);
```

> "-91.57696007",
>       "10.343234",
>       "74.982343",
>       "76.464844",
>       "76.464844",

But how to convert total dataset into `float` on iOS?

---

If we use `OjectAtIndex:0` it takes first position but I have to store total response into single float value without using `OjectAtIndex:0` in iphone.

Comment: Accept correct answer it helps to others

Comment: if you can clarify little more then we may be able to help you

Comment: uhmm, are you asking (in your edit) how to do addition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
float x = [[Array objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
```